# Electronic soldering and repair for a newbie

Tags: soldering, repair

So, recently, I've been trying to get more skilled with electronics to prepare me for college, starting with soldering. I mentioned this to someone I know, and he gave me his broken E-Cig, saying I could try to fix it for some experience, and that he'd pay me if I could get it working. I've looked up some basic stuff, but I'm still pretty nervous, and wanted to know if any knowledgeable people would be willing to give any advice to a newbie like me (I'd ask someone else for help, but no one I know is very good with electronics).

I'm including some photos below. From what he said, the only thing wrong is the tip of these two red wires from the mouthpiece to the H+ and H- spots on the main pcb, which snapped off when he dropped it.
Any help would be appreciated, but I'm really looking for:

- General steps to how you would fix it
- Soldering tips for someone who's never done this before
- How to get the solder that's currently in the hole out... I saw something online about heating it up and using a solder sucker, but I don't have one of those. Any other way I can fix this?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Get a solder sucker. It's a basic tool.

Comment: Or some solder wick.

Answer (score 1):

Get some solder wicking braid if you really want to mess with removing the old solder.

Otherwise, just re-use the old solder by melting it, pulling out the old, snapped-off wire bits, then insert the new wire ends through the molten solder pools.

As a more important tip, buy a **quality** soldering iron/station.

- If you're not sure how committed you are to doing soldering/EE work, then you can buy something like a Hakko FX600 iron for ~$40 that will do a decent job (anything that costs less, isn't worth throwing away, IMO).
- If you're more sure of your commitment, something more like an FX888D is much better, and your soldering abilities are likely to improve faster while learning with it!